# MySQL Sakila count the films Penelope Guiness starred in

Tags: mysql, sql

Just as the title says I need to count how many films did penelope starred in knowing just his first and last name.

I know it would have COUNT in it but I can piece together the query, the best I can come up with is:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM film_actor WHERE ( SELECT actor.actor_id FROM actor WHERE (actor.first_name = "PENELOPE") AND (actor.last_name = "GUINESS"));`

and it doesn't really return the data I need, it just counts ALL of the actor_id from the film.

It returns the count 5462 instead of just 19

Comment: you should have the field from film_actor table after where clause to compare against the actor.actor_id something like "where film_actor.actor_id in (select actor.actor_id....)"

Comment: What is the schema of the `film_actor` table?

Comment: I suspect Penelope preferred the pronoun 'her'

Answer (score 0):

please add the table definition for **film_actor** and **actor**

My first try would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM film_actor AS f JOIN actor AS a ON f.actor_id = a.actor_id WHERE a.first_name = "PENELOPE" AND a.last_name = "GUINESS";
```

this connects the table film_actor  with the table actor. But not every row, only rows where actor_id is the same. Like this

```
[film_actor]                 [actor]

movie_name | actor_id        actro_id | first_name | last_name
-----------+----------       ---------+------------+-----------
AAA        |   15            15       | PENELOPE   |  GUINESS 
BBB        |   11            11       | aaa        |  last_aaa 
CCC        |   15            10       | bbb        |  last_bbb
DDD        |   10            69       | xxx        |  last_xxx
XXX        |   69



[JOIN Table]

movie_name | actro_id | first_name | last_name
-----------+----------+------------+-------------
AAA        |    15    | PENELOPE   |  GUINESS 
BBB        |    11    | aaa        |  last_aaa 
CCC        |    15    | PENELOPE   |  GUINESS 
DDD        |    10    | bbb        |  last_bbb
AAA        |    69    | xxx        |  last_xxx
```

And then it only take the rows where first_name="PENELOPE" and last_name="GUINESS "

And count the lines

Comment: If the film_actor table included 'role' (it doesn't - but hypothetically), then it's possible that the same actor could be associated with the same film more than once, in which case we would need `COUNT(DISTINCT film_id)`, but the above is fine for the actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery would return an error in many databases, because `actorid` is not a valid comparison . . . it is not compared to anything.

MySQL allows this, treating `0` as false and other values as true.  Hence, the `where` clause probably evaluates to true for all rows.

There are two issues to fix this:

1. The subquery should be checking -- row by row -- the actor in the outer query.  This is called a *correlation* clause.
2. You want `exists`, not to just return an arbitrary id.

So, the query you are trying to write would seem to be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM film_actor fa
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM actor a
              WHERE a.actor_id = fa.actor_id AND
--------------------^ correlation clause
                    a.first_name = 'PENELOPE' AND 
                    a.last_name = 'GUINESS'
             );
```

Note:  This assumes that actors don't have multiple roles in a film (that would be listed multiple times in `film_actor`.  If that is possible, you want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fa.film_id)
```